# Jelly Bean starts googlequicksearchbox when pressing back button

Tags: android, google-search, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an application and on Motorola XOOM with Android 4.1 it starts Google Search activity when I am pressing back button on video player activity in my application. No intents for Google search have been sent from this application. Also it works properly on previous android versions even ICS devices. Here is the logs

```
09-05 14:19:53.260: I/InputReader(271): Reconfiguring input devices.changes=0x00000004
09-05 14:19:53.260: I/InputReader(271): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='qtouch-touchscreen', surface size is now 1280x800, mode is 1
09-05 14:19:53.360: I/ActivityManager(271): Config changed: {1.0 0mcc0mnc en_US sw800dp     w800dp h1232dp xlrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.37}
09-05 14:19:53.410: D/myTag(11672): com.orvis.container.OKnot@41b7f650
09-05 14:19:53.440: D/dalvikvm(1231): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 5% free 7967K/8327K, paused 9ms+6ms, total 70ms
09-05 14:19:53.460: W/AudioFlinger(93): session id 764 not found for pid 11672
09-05 14:19:53.510: I/ActivityManager(271): START {act=android.intent.action.ASSIST flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/.SearchActivity u=0} from pid 344
```

Please assist.
Thank you.

Comment: are you somehow overriding the back button?

Comment: no, it uses standard onBackPressed() method, without any additional code.